# Implementation of "Rule of Three" gone wrong

Tags: c++, delete-operator, rule-of-three

Below is an erroneous implementation of "The rule of three", which I try to understand.

Debugging the program, I found that the debugger has a problem cleaning up  `int *k`, which could be resolved either by defining `int *k = nullptr` or simply setting it to something reasonable in the copy constructor.

However, I do not understand how the resulting error of the program, an access violation, comes into existence.

I do know, after the copy assignment constructor `v1`'s `int *k`no longer points to a valid memory address.

```
class Vector2 {
public:
    std::string name = "default";
    int* k;

    Vector2(int s, std::string n) : k(new int[s]), name(n) {
    }

    Vector2(const Vector2 &other)  {
        std::cout<< "Copy constructor: " << name << std::endl;
    }

    ~Vector2() {
        std::cout << "Deleting: " << name << std::endl;
        delete[] k;
    }

    void swap(Vector2& other) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(k, other.k);
    }

    Vector2& operator=(Vector2 other) {
        std::cout << "Copy assignment constructor: " << name << std::endl;
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }
};


int main() {
        Vector2 v1 = Vector2(2, "v1");
        Vector2 v2 = Vector2(4, "v2");
        v1 = v2;
        std::cout << &v1 << " " << &v2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << &v1.k << " " << &v2.k << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Below is the console output of above's program:

```
Copy constructor: default
Copy assignment constructor: v1
Deleting: default
0000001B5611FA28 0000001B5611FA78
0000001B5611FA50 0000001B5611FAA0
Deleting: v2
Deleting: v1
16:18:42: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Comment: From C++11 and onward, it is the [Rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html) though.

Comment: From C++98 and onward, the rule of zero is your friend ;)

Comment: Does your copy-constructor, actually do any copying?

Comment: You also need to pass the Vector2 into your copy assignment operator by reference. Ideally as a const reference but I'm not sure if that's absolutely necessary

Comment: @Tharwen that's the very point of the rule of three/five: you do **not** need to do that :)

Comment: I would highlight that debugging programs is a skill that must be learnt - and using a debugger is an essential skill if you plan to do any programming (except for arduino work - where I don't think one exists).  Learning how to do this is should be moved up your priority list rather than learning about the rule of 3/5

Comment: You must have a *working*, non-buggy copy constructor, and a *working*, non-buggy destructor for the rule of 3 to work.  Your copy constructor doesn't copy anything -- bug.  Bottom line is that the copy constructor cannot be a "stub" function that is basically empty -- either you implement it fully, or declare it as `delete`-ed.  You cannot run the program reliably with a stub copy constructor or actually any of the 3 functions as stubs to be filled in later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be derived by laying out the exact sequence of events, e.g.: More print outs and testing, what parameters are called when:

Starting in: `v1 = v2;`

1. `v2` calls **copy constructor** with the argument other (whatever other is), in particular: its `int* k` does not point to valid memory. For simplicity let's call this new Vector2 v3.
2. The **copy assignment constructor** is called now with v3.
3. Then we begin swap.

The error actually arises within the **copy constructor**, as `v3` is not initialised properly in step 1 .

Step 2 and step 3 are basically "hiding", transferring the error from `v3` onto `v1`.

The interesting question now is, how is `v3` actually generated? Not by the default constructor!

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very simple: Your copy constructor does not make a copy. In fact, it does not initialize any member, so any instance created by this constructor is filled with crap.

For the call of `operator=(Vector2 other)` the copy constructor is called to create `other` (this is the point of the rule of three), so `other` is filled with crap.
Then you swap the valid `k` of `this` (aka `v1`) with the crappy `k` of `other`.

Then, when the destructor of `v1` is called, it calls `delete[] k` on a crappy `k` --> access violation.

### Solution

Make your copy constructor make a copy. Or at least, make it properly initialize `k` (e.g. to `nullptr`).

Answer (score 0):

Constructing `other` in `operator=` uses the copy constructor, which does not create a new copy of the pointed to value. Your copy constructor may not even copy `k` since it is a POD type and therefore not necessarily default constructed or default copied.

Then when it is destructed it tries to destroy it twice. Or depending on random factors like stack layout, it may not copy `k` at all and then it tries to `delete` an invalid pointer.

Comment: It is not destroyed twice.  Newly constructed object does not initialize `k`, resulting in the crash when the destructor tries to delete this uninitialized value.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Did you try it because I got a copy. OR the same pointer somehow. But you're technically right and I updated my answer.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I think so too - as written - k does not point to a valid memory address. At which step though does it become invalid?

Comment: @Imago It never *becomes* invalid. It was never valid to start with because it is never set explicitly by the copy constructor.

Comment: Why not? It had called the constructor for `v1`, so not using the copy assignment constructor makes above's code completely valid.

Comment: It isn't overwriting `v1` in `operator=`. It creates an entirely new copy because the function parameter is not a reference.

Comment: Or, OK. `v1` becomes invalid when `swap` overwrites its `k` with the `other.k`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in `Vector2(const Vector2 &other)`

You use this constructor in your `operator =` implicitly by passing by value; but you fail to assign k to any value in that constructor.

This results in swap replacing a valid k with an invalid k, and then deleting the invalid k; resulting in your crash.